# Отсортировать фрейм данных по порядку, заданному индексом другого фрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных, индексация

Eсть 2 дата фрейма, нужно отсортировать второй датафрейм по порядку индексов первого. То есть если

```
df1.index = ["mother", "sister", "brother"]
df2['A'] = ["brother","mother", "sister"]
```

то нужно весь дата фрейм отсортировать как df1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df1.index.to_list():
    res=pd.concat([res, df2.loc[df2["A"]==i]])
```

res:

```
         A
1   mother
2   sister
0  brother
```